# Python FileNotFound Django test media

Tags: python, django, assertion, file-not-found

I'm creating a django project that will accept user content, and during development I'm trying to create a test case that will test that the model uploads normally.

I have a file structure like so:

```
Site
|----temp
|    |----django-test
|----app
     |----test_image.jpg
     |----test_manual.pdf
     |----tests.py
```

My test case code is such:

```
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings
from django.core.files import File
import sys
import os

from .models import Manual

# Create your tests here.
class ManualModelTests(TestCase):
    @override_settings(MEDIA_ROOT='/tmp/django_test')
    def test_normal_manual_upload(self):
        in_image = open(os.path.join('manuals','test_image.jpg'), 'r+b')
        in_pdf = open(os.path.join('manuals','test_manual.pdf'), 'r+b')

        thumbnail = File(in_image)
        in_manual = File(in_pdf)

        new_manual = Manual.objects.create(
            photo=thumbnail, 
            manual=in_manual, 
            make='yoshimura', 
            model='001', 
            year_min=2007, 
            year_max=2010
        )
#uploaded_image = open(os.path.join('temp','django_test','images','test_image.jpg'), 'r+b')
#uploaded_pdf = open(os.path.join('temp','django_test','manuals','test_manual.pdf'), 'r+b')    #self.assertIs(open(), in_image)
#self.assertIs(uploaded_img, in_image)
#self.assertIs(uploaded_pdf, in_pdf)
```

Here is the model code:

```
class Manual(models.Model):
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos")
make = models.CharField(max_length=50)
model = models.CharField(max_length=100)
manual = models.FileField(upload_to="manuals")
year_min = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
year_max = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

For some reason I'm getting a FileNotFound upon opening 'test_image.jpg'). My questions are

1. Why am I getting this error and how do I rectify it?
2. Does my commented section using self.assertIs look correct?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a `FileNotFoundError` because `open` will try and locate the files relative to the current working directory, which is probably `Site`.

It may be better to open the files using a path relative to the test module itself, using `__file__`, as that wouldn't depend on the current working directory. For example:

```
open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'test_image.jpg'), 'r+b')
```

For the assertions, it may be easiest just to test for the existence of the uploaded files. If they exist, then the upload must have worked. For example:

```
self.assertTrue(os.path.exists('/tmp/django_test/test_image.jpg'))
```

You should also add a `tearDown()` method to your test to remove the uploaded files once the test finishes.

```
def tearDown(self):
    try:
        os.remove('/tmp/django_test/test_image.jpg')
    except FileNotFoundError: 
        pass
```